# How do you specify a minimum Ruby version in a gemspec?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a gemspec for a new version of a gem that will now require Ruby 1.9. Previous versions of the gem were ok with Ruby 1.8, but now 1.9 will be required. Is there a way to cause the gem install for this version of the gem to fail with a warning for users who try to install it on Ruby 1.8?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

From the [RubyGems documentation](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#required_ruby_version=):

```
# This gem will work with 1.8.6 or greater...
spec.required_ruby_version = '>= 1.8.6'

# Only with ruby 2.0.x
spec.required_ruby_version = '~> 2.0'
```

Comment: Can you specify a patch level?  I get `Illformed requirement [">= 1.9.3-p551"]` using `gem 1.8.23.2`.

Answer (score -2):

```
gem.required_ruby_version = '1.9.2'
```

Should solve your problem :-)

Comment: Can I write that like '>= 1.9.0' ?

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation that covers this too? Thanks

Comment: Sure! You can write gem.required_ruby_version = '>= 1.9.2'. Check out http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20 for more :-)

Comment: This will require exactly version 1.9.2.  You need ">= 1.9.2" in order to require 1.9.2 or later. See https://github.com/frodsan/mongoid-minitest/pull/9