# Does Bundler Gem take in consideration your Ruby environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

My question is simple one, does gem bundler considers your ruby environment (e.g. 1.8.7 | 1.9.2) before deciding which gem to take based on gem file?

Let's say your gemfile contains

```
gem 'thor'
gem 'json'
gem 'grit'
```

When you run `bundle install` will take versions of the gem that are compatible with your current ruby environment or just latest gems?

Comment: Based on this (http://gembundler.com/rationale.html) it seems that the above Gemfile would give you the latest versions of the gems, but this (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions) suggests you can specify your Ruby version in your Gemfile.

Comment: The Heroku suggestion is within a different context. It defines the Targe-Environment and is used to tell Heroku to run applications with 1.9 or 1.8. So i think it does not apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends! Bundler relies on the configuration of the Gemspecs that each Gem provides.

Gemspecs offer the posibility to provide different or additional dependencies based on the runtime environment. IE you can change the dependencies for JRuby or provide different binaries for i386 architectures.

As far as i know, it's not possible to declare a gem as 1.9 or 1.8 compatible (which would have made sense to me). I think it's partly so, because 1.9 is 99% downward compatible.

You are always forced to have a look at the gems themselves. Because of this, there are sites like http://isitruby19.com/

As you might see, it's not an issue of Bundler, but RubyGems.

Comment: Gemfiles spec allow specifying version of ruby, more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004492/how-do-you-specify-a-minimum-ruby-version-in-a-gemspec.

Comment: You are correct. The problem with this is, that it's an optional configuration and just 1 out of 4 gems use it at all, most of them just define a ```>= 1.8.x``` wich is kind of useless in your case...

Comment: I've tested in two different Ruby environments 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 and from what I can see, unless you specify version you get the latest. Maybe all gems I used are both 1.8.x and 1.9.x compatible but unless there is better answer let's stick to bundler does not look into ruby env version.